# awk unable to ignore "++"

Tags: bash, awk

```
check="a1++"
awk -F":" -v name="$check" 'tolower($2)~ tolower(name)' file.txt
```

It seems that there are some issue with awk when working with a string of "++". It unable to retrieve the value in the file. However,I have tried to change `check="44b"` it seems to be working perfectly fine

```
apple:44b:Vietnam
orange:A1++ approved:China
jelly:-34:Malaysia
pear:98:Malaysia
```

file.txt

Comment: why `-F":"` instead of `-F","` ?

Comment: apologies, forgot to change back to original code while doing some testing

Comment: What is the expected output? That code returns `orange:A1++:China` (tested).
`

Comment: expected "orange:A1++:China"

Comment: This works for me, with `-F","`

Comment: Note that regex will also match the line `foo:a1:bar` because `+` is a regex special character. If you want to check if the *string* "a1++" is in $2, do `'index(tolower($2), tolower(name))'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Glenn Jackman mentioned in comments, you should be using `index` vs `~` since `+` is a regex metacharacter.

If you use `++` then `orange:A123 approved:China` would also match...

You can do:

```
$ awk -F: -v name="$check" 'index(tolower($2), tolower(name))' file
```

Comment: If `gawk`, you could have set `BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}`

Comment: That only works for a regex -- not a string comparison. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

this works on my `awk` but don't use since the right hand side is treated as regex and special characters will take over.  If regex match is not intended, substring match with `index` is better as in the other answer.

```
$ check="a1++"; awk -F: -v name="$check" 'tolower($2)~tolower(name)' file

orange:A1++:China
```

check your `awk` version, perhaps it's broken

or with the other input

```
$ check="a1++"; awk -F: -v name="$check" 'tolower($2)~tolower(name)' file

orange:A1++ approved:China
```

will match as expected, note that "name" is on the right hand side of the regex match and "$2" is on the left.

Comment: thanks but it seems that if i change the raw file data to "orange:A1++ approved:China". It doesnt work :(

Comment: thanks but when I am trying to list only those numbers which has a ++ symbol in it. The system seems to reject my input "awk: run time error: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)"

Comment: what is your `awk` version?

Comment: Since using `++` in a regexp doesn't make sense, I suspect you're running into undefined behavior and so any awk can interpret it however it likes. Normally I'd look up the standards to check but it's just something that should never be used since it's confusing code at best so no point doing chapter and verse...